# SSRS 2008 matrices with stepped column

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report, ssrs-tablix

Got a requirement for creating fancy report in SSRS 2008. it's in the matrix format, but instead of normal columns that grows to the right, they want something like stepped rows for column
Something like this:

```
    col1
        col2
            col3
row1
row2
row3
```

instead of the standard matrix

```
    col1 col2 col3
row1
row2
row3
```

Can anyone suggest to me how to do this? 
Have no idea how to start :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end to do this I give up on using matrices and use subreports instead.
I separate the report into three pieces. one main report with two subreports. the header is main report, two subreports is in left and right, all using tablix. the main report has some custom code added for accumulating spaces and achieving desired "stepped" effect
it's possible to achieve better visual design if we use background image for the lines instead, but this will have to do for now :)

[End result http://imageshack.com/a/img537/5421/fVNAo4.jpg](http://imageshack.com/a/img537/5421/fVNAo4.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use expression below in the cell for column group.

```
=Switch(Fields!col.Value="col1","col01"&chr(10)&chr(10),
Fields!col.Value="col2",chr(10)&"col2"&chr(10),
Fields!col.Value="col3",chr(10)&chr(10)&"col3")
```

Then it can look like "step down" effect for the column headers.

Comment: the col comes from database, so there is a dynamic number of them. that's why I need matrix at first place. yours might work if I have fixed number of columns right?